# Get row selected from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I am trying to use the index of the selected row in my segue. I have a UITableViewController as the class type so i know it has the delegate and the datasource however when i try to use the DidSelectRowAt indexPath: indexPath function, the function is never called. Any help would be great. I have done some research into this and others have had a UIView with a TableView ontop of it and not had the TableView standing alone.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleBooksApiClient

class SearchResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var titleFromSearch: String?
var authorFromSearch: String?

var index = 0 
var data = [Volume]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

.............................

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ................
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    index = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController{
        destination.titleOfBook = data[index].volumeInfo.title
    }
}
```

}

I still maintain my same question. I really appreciate all the comments and help from everyone but i am still having issue with getting this to work. I have tried using a local variable to be able to use along with passing IndexPath using performSegue but i am still having issues with getting DidSelectRowAt to be called and actually be able to use the row which was selected.

Comment: I am sure `UITableView` have a `indexPathForSelectedRow:IndexPath?` property or `indexPathsForSelectedRows:[IndexPath]?`(for multiple selection enabled) to retrieve the selected indexes on requirement

Comment: I do not find either of those functions as an override in UITableView. Are you saying i would write that myself then?

Comment: Those are not functions... they are just property you can call from your tableview to get selected indexes something like:`myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`

Comment: If you're using a `UITableViewController` then the only thing the view controller's view can contain is a table view. It's not possible for it to be "a UIView with a TableView ontop of it". A `UITableViewController` must have a table view as the content view, and nothing else.

Comment: Im not sure i am following this idea. My class is called SearchResultsTableViewController. And you are saying i should be able to do SearchResultsTableViewController.indexPathForSelectedRow ?

Comment: Duncan - what i meant by on top of it is that i have seen solutions with a UIViewController and then have a TableView inside it, like embedded

Comment: Make sure there is content in the array with which the table view is populated. Also check you have returned aleast 1 for both numberofsectionsInTableView and numberofRowsInSection. Otherwise didSelectRow will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

The method name for `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` has to match exactly:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

If optional delegate methods aren't named correctly, they won't get called.

When you invoke your segue from that method by calling `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`, you can pass the indexPath of the selected cell in the sender parameter, then use that indexPath in your `prepare(for:sender:)` method

Comment: I tried to comment the code i have written but it wouldnt format so i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

People put tableView on `UIView` for more flexibility, so that the view can also include other UI elements like label, switch and button.

For you problem, I suppose you have mistakenly set

```
self.tableView.allowsSelection = false
```

or

```
self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

you may need to look the above two settings in Interface builder as well, if you use Interface builder

Comment: I have set both of those to true in my code and i do use interface builder. Now, is there a way to ensure the prepareForSegue gets called after the DidSelectRowAt?

Comment: call self.performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:) in function tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)

Comment: Do i have to change my prepare to perform like i have in my question?

Comment: No need, but two things 1. in case your if let destination returns nil, handle it as well so you will know. 2. Actually no need to call super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender), the parent class methond did nothing, fyi: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepareforsegue

Comment: I removed the super because it doesnt do anything but i cannot get the self.performSegue to build. What would be my identifier?

Comment: select the segue in the interface builder, you can input your custom identifier for this segue, and then put it in performSegue(withIdentifier: "your identifier", sender: self)